# Hardware & software for streaming phone display

Tags: wireless, embedded, bluetooth, protocol

I'm looking to create a projector which projects my phone screen onto a wall. I have a few requirements:

1. I'd like to do it using a projector with its own light source (i.e. I don't want to use a lens that focuses the phone's display to shine on the wall).
2. I'd like it to be wireless.
3. I'm not interested in the actual light source implementation: more specifically, I'd like to understand the protocol & mechanism to send the phone screen info wirelessly to an embedded device, and then how that info can be output in a format that could then be recognised by a remote projector / lcd display.

I'd essentially like it to be like this: https://www.snopes.com/photos/technology/cicret.asp, only onto a wall (rather than my arm) and the touch-screen functionality that circret has isn't necessary.

Could someone give me some suggestions as to the hardware that I could use to do this? [edit: using existing hardware to pair with my mobile device is the ideal solution]. Something I can reverse engineer is the ideal solution I have in mind: i.e. if circret was on the market, I would take out the electronics that I needed in order to project and voila. Obviously, I would like the cheapest solution. If worst came to worst: could someone give me a solution that involved me having to code something? (I'd like to do as little coding as possible).

Comment: So you're asking how you can project your phone's activities onto a screen? Why not emulate a mobile device via software? Something like [Bluestacks?](https://www.bluestacks.com/#gref)

Comment: You have no idea what you're getting into and you are _way_ over your head.

Comment: @KingDuken Bluestacks would be a good shout if I wanted to have it on my pc screen. But I'm looking to create a display that's portable & its only function is to display the phone screen. Still a good comment 'cuz Bluestacks is pretty interesting!

Comment: I think it would be pretty easy to just connect a chromecast to a projector, and then cast your screen like this (https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=en-IN)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

(originally a comment)

Just plug a [chromecast](https://store.google.com/product/chromecast_2015) into a [projector](http://uk.pcmag.com/projector-reviews/65529/guide/the-best-portable-projectors-of-2017) and [cast your screen](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=en-IN)

Comment: Perfect. Dunno why I didn't think of this!! (might wanna cast the screen onto an LCD screen instead - which wouldn't have HDMI -
 but I'm pretty sure this is the best solution we'll get!).

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neewer-Black-Adapter-Converter-Laptop/dp/B007KEIRNG
https://www.amazon.co.uk/kenable-Socket-Digital-Speed-Adapter-White/dp/B01M3XE2JW/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1516995766&sr=1-5&keywords=hdmi+socket+dvi

Comment: Product recommendations _and_ consumer electronics are off-topic. Please keep this in mind when feeding lazy OPs who can't read the rules.